# Specification of regression model based on two data sources

Tags: regression, standardization, model-comparison

Suppose that I have two different datasets from surveys in which the dependent variable is measured on different scales and I want to evaluate the effect the survey method (i.e. the measuring scale) has on the outcome variable. Let's say e.g. I want to estimate a regression model where the dependent variable is the hours of study and in survey 1 this is measured as hrs per day and in survey 2 it is hrs per week.

The aim is to be able to compare the sign and magnitude of the regression parameters from the different datasets.

Now my idea is to combine the datasets and estimate a regression model in which I standardize the dependent variable and use interaction parameters for the different survey methods. The independent variables are all measured on the same scale / have the same attribute levels.

Is this approach sensible? Would I need to standardize the independent variables as well?

Thanks!

Comment: These aren't different scales: they are merely different *units of measurement.*  Upon expressing the responses in a common unit of measurement there should be no problem.  But if you combine the datasets without using a common unit of measurement, the result will be nonsense.

Comment: Thanks, that just kept me from totally messing up the analysis! Now that I read it, it actually is obvious that I am not talking about scales. 

Now I think I can just refer to all the other questions and answers on standardizations of variables. :)

Comment: Just make sure you express all results in a common unit of measurement *before* you do any standardization.